# How to install Weblogic 14.1.1 into Eclipse 2021

Tags: eclipse, weblogic

I tried to install Weblogic 14.1.1 into my Eclipse 2021.
I followed this guide:
https://blogs.oracle.com/weblogicserver/post/weblogic-server-14-in-eclipse-ide-for-java-ee-developers

But I run into the errors that some jre 16 seems to be in the way.
Do you guys got any clue how to solve this?
Best regards
Fredrik
[image: Install error]
[image: Start error]

Comment: I found this information under Eclipse > Help > About Eclipse IDE > Installation Details > Configuration

Comment: -vm
/home/fredrik/Applications/eclipse_2021//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.linux.x86_64_16.0.2.v20210721-1149/jre/bin/java and some other values pointing to this jre. I guess I need to change this, but how?

Comment: At first, WLS 14c is only supported with Oracle JDK 8 or 11.
Open JDK is not supported.
Java versions after 11 are not supported also.

Comment: In this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70508100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70508100/cannot-install-oracle-weblogic-server-tools-in-eclipse?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top) explain: How install weblogic in eclipse 2021.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Weblogic 12c and Eclipse 2021. Until someone can provide us a better solution, you can use eclipse 2019 (the way I solved it).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31068419)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do the installation.
I will explain the steps:

1. Add to the end of the eclipse.ini file: `--add-opens=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar=ALL-UNNAMED`
2. Open Eclipse and go to the "Help > About Eclipse IDE" menu. In the window that opens, click on the "Installation Details" button. Look for the "JustJ JRE for IDE Packages" plugin (which contains an embedded JRE in Eclipse), select it, and click the "Uninstall..." button.
3. Edit the eclipse.ini file and add the JRE configuration to run Eclipse. You need to know which version of Eclipse you are using to determine the compatible version. Current versions (as of this date) are using Java 17 `(C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17.0.10/bin/javaw.exe)`.

```
... previous content
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17.0.10/bin/javaw.exe
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=17
...subsequent content
```

4. Let's go to the "Help > Install New Software..." menu. In the window that opens, click on the "Add..." button. Add the new option with the values "Oracle WebLogic 14 Plugin Eclipse" and "http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.2.1.10/photon/repository/".
5. Proceed with the installation, but attention, on the screen to select the features to install, select only these 2 options: "Oracle WebLogic Scriptin Tools" and "Oracle WebLogic Server Tools"

Now it's just time to have fun!